# how to read query params in angular authguard Canactivate

Tags: angular, authentication, guard

I tried to read query params inside authguard in angular 9.but getting undefined,
I haves et authguard with Canactivate

Comment: do you mind sharing the code you have tried (as part of the question) ?

Comment: post your trying'